# Convergence of an infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a nonzero sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, with $a_{n+1}\geq a_{n}$  for all $n$, and $\inf_{n}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})=r>0$.

Does this implies that the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}^{2}}$ converges?

Comment: Well, the smallest that $a_{n+1}$ can be is $a_n+r$.  So, it suffices to study the series $a_0+nr$.

Comment: So if the condition $\inf_{n}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})=r>0$ is not satisfied, do we still have the result?

Comment: This should be phrased as a new question, but certainly not because $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a counterexample in this case an the squares become the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2):

One may observe that
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)+a_1\geq (n-1)\times r+a_1
$$ and that there is an $n_0$ such that $a_{n_0}\ge a_1+(n_0-1)r\gt0$

giving $$
\begin{align}0<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n^2} &\le\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}\frac1{a_n^2} +\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty\frac1{\left(a_{n_0}+(n-n_0)r\right)^2}\end{align}
$$
 and **your initial series is convergent** since the latter series is convergent (one may use the limit comparison test to prove it):
$$
\frac{1}{((n-n_0)\times r+a_1)^{2}}\sim \frac{1}{r^2 n^2}, \quad n \to \infty.
$$

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: it is given that $a_n\ne0$, but there is the possibility that for some $n$, $a_1+nr=0$, in which case, the summation on the right of your middle inequality is not defined. One way to fix this is to note that there is an $n_0$ so that $a_{n_0}\ge a_1+(n_0-1)r\gt0$, then $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n^2} &\le\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}\frac1{a_n^2} +\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty\frac1{\left(a_{n_0}+(n-n_0)r\right)^2}\\ &=\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}\frac1{a_n^2} +\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\left(a_{n_0}+nr\right)^2}\end{align}$$ Then the sum on the right is defined (as well as convergent).

Comment: +1 Although what I say above makes the proof more accurate, it may cloud the basic idea, which is good in any case.

Comment: However, they didn't say that $a_1\gt0$, only that $a_n\ne0$.

Comment: My bad, I red: $a_n>0$, but it is just given that $a_n \neq 0$. I will edit my answer. Thank you very much for the catch!